# Rotate object around x,y,z axis in threejs

Tags: three.js

i need to rotate the object that is i loaded using OBJMTLLoder, so i used the following code to rotate the object around it axis, but it doesn't working at all

```
var rotation =0;
function rotateX()
{
    rotation += 1.5;
    xradians = globalObject.rotation.x+rotation;
    yradians = globalObject.rotation.y;
    zradians = globalObject.rotation.z;
    globalObject.rotation.set( xradians, yradians, zradians );
}
```

where `globalObject` is the global variable which is assigned for object that is loaded

Comment: Why dont you simply do rotateX() { globalObject.rotation.x += 1.5; }

Comment: Not working as well as @gaitat,

Comment: what is the error message? Does `console.log(globalObject)` output something?

Comment: No am getting my object details like object id,name and etc, on before the rotation i checked  if(globalObject){   alert('hi'); console.log(globalObject);  globalObject.rotation.x += 1.5;    //camera.position.x = 200;} and the condition is working and it alerted